# Why substracting two Dates gives me an extra hour?

Tags: scala

I wanted to perform some benchmarks on some methods of my program so I wrote this little snippet

```
object ExecutionTime {

  private val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss")

  private var timeList = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()

  def startTimer() : Long = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    start
  }

  def getExecutionTime(start : Long) {
    val executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
    timeList.+=(format.format(new Date(executionTime)))
  }

  def printResults() {
    timeList.mkString(" /n ")
  }
}
```

To test this, I ran this little piece of code :

```
object Test {
  val begin = ExecutionTime.startTimer()
  waitFor2Seconds()
  ExecutionTime.getExecutionTime(begin)
  ExecutionTime.printResults()
}
```

However, when I run this I am getting a strange output :

```
01:00:02 // Should be 00:00:02
```

The result I have is the one that I expect, but with 1 extra hour.
Anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: By chance, are you in a location with a timezone that is 1 hour after greenwich mean time?  I ask because you are constructing a Date with the timedelta that is measured, the date formatter may be translating to "local time"...

Comment: Indeed I am GMT+1 ! Is there a trick to format in GMT+1?

Comment: `Date` objects are really not meant to store a duration in. A `Date` format is a timestamp, not a duration. Use the Java 8 `java.time` API instead of the old `java.util.Date` if you're running on a Java 8 JVM. You'd use `java.time.Duration` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are constructing a `Date` object using the time delta between clock measurements.  Therefore the `SimpleDateFormat` is translating the Date to local time when constructing the String.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (emphasis mine):

> SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates
>   in a **locale-sensitive manner**.

Your constructed Date is epoch + 2 seconds, so your local time must be (epoch + 1 hour + 2 seconds); and that is what the formatter is printing.

To have SimpleDateFormat print without the 1 hour addition you need to set the locale to be GMT and change your hour format to be `"HH"`:

```
private val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
format.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
```

Comment: That is probably the right way to go, unfortunately "GMT" TimeZone gives me 12:00:02, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)) isn't really clear and GMT+1:00 gives me the same results as before

Comment: Change the format to "HH:mm:ss" (note the capital 'H').

Comment: Thanks ! I will remember to use capital "H" next time!

Answer (score 2):

As another suggestion, look into the Joda time library ([here's a scala wrapper](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time)). This library can be used to easily subtract and add periods of time and convert to time formats on the fly. I much prefer it to the SimpleDateFormat class.